# Access from input directly from id

Tags: javascript, html, input, getelementbyid

I just discovered a feature that I didn't know about to access to input value.

Let's say that I have the following input in my HTML template:

```
<input type="text" id="myinput" />
```

Until then, I used to access to the value of the input through the following line:

```
var myinput = document.getElementById("myinput");
var value = myinput.value;
```

And this is the solution that I found in every post about this topic. But it seems that (recent?) browsers actually do the first line automatically because I can access to the value of my input directly through:

```
var value = myinput.value
```

We can see a working example here: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/lgwE0WBwU1fwH9GBaAnV?p=preview)

It seems fair for the browsers to do that automatically but I cannot find any resource that documentate this feature. Perhaps I didn't search well enough but if anyone can explain this to me, it would be good.

Comment: I think you are looking for this.https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563638/how-do-i-get-the-value-of-text-input-field-using-javascript

Comment: I saw that post but I cannot find any reference to the method allowing to access to the value of an input directly using it id, so without calling `document.getElementById()` method